# Checkpoint NGX FW1 Routing Between Networks

Tags: networking, firewall, routing, checkpoint

We have an old Checkpoint NGX FW1 firewall which we have to maintain. For the most part we leave it alone and it just chuggs away and works. The person who originally set it up left years ago and we've muddled though administering it for years.

Today I want to add a new network to it. Something we've done before when we want to connect a customers network to our network.

Setup as follows:

```
(InternalNet)    <-> Switch     <-> Checkpoint Eth0      <0> Checkpoint Eth2 <-> Customers Router <-> (CustomersNetwork)
192.168.10.0    192.168.10.253          172.16.0.1         10.180.28.190/240    10.180.28.177/240
```

The firewall becomes a routing device. Not ideal, however it's what we have to deal with.

I have adjusted the OS IP for the NIC (linux based OS) using sysconfig and added the IP into the SmartDashboard, Checkpoint topology area. Created a network under 'Networks' for the new  network as configured the topology for eth2 to use the specific customers network I setup.

I've also added a rule in the firewall to allow internal traffic to access the customers network.

With this configuration from the checkpoint OS I can ping the customers router and get a response. I can also ping another device I have attached to the customers router.

I can't ping past eth2 NIC from my network. I can ping eth2 IP and get a response, but I don't get a response from the router if I ping it from my laptop.

Other NIC traffic (it's also used as a external internet gateway) works fine on eth3.

I have missed a step, but I don't know what.

How can I correctly configure the FW to route 10.180.28.176/240 traffic to the correct NIC from my internal network.

Comment: What is the default gateway of the router? If not checkpoint, is there a route saying that 192.168.10.0/24 should go thru 10.180.28.190?

Comment: You know what, I have no idea. It arrived and I can connect to the customers network if a PC is hooked directly too it on the same range but I doubt it has any routes in it for our network. A very good point.